# Can't login to Xbox account on Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an Xbox account, and I am attempting to login to my Minecraft Pocket Edition for iOS with it. But when I finish login, it gives me this error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong. Give it another try, or try on Xbox.com

[image: Error Message]

What can I do?

Comment: I don't think the Xbox version of Minecraft is Pocket Edition.

Comment: @Frank You might have missed the announcement during Microsoft's E3 show. PE with xbox achievements for the iOS and Android was officially released literally 4 days ago with the announcement

Comment: @Frank - [reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/4mpz4z/minecraft_pe_on_ios_android_get_xbox_achievements/) for the above comment from deutschZuid. Does seem to be the case.